# How to determine if a Type is of RunTimeType?

Tags: c#

How do I determine if a Type is of type RunTimeType?  I have this working but it is kind of kludgy:

```
    private bool IsTypeOfType(Type type)
    {
        return type.FullName ==  "System.RuntimeType";
    }
```

Comment: Why do you need to know that?

Comment: Haven't tried this in particular. Wouldn't type == typeof(RuntimeType) work?

Comment: @ThatChuckGuy, that won't work, because `RuntimeType` is `internal`.

Comment: @svick Oh, ok. Guess that shows that I've never had to use one, huh?

Comment: I am using this for: http://comparenetobjects.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I guess that you actually want to know if a `Type` object describes the `Type` class, but the `Type` object is `typeof(RuntimeType)` and not `typeof(Type)` and so comparing it to `typeof(Type)` fails.

What you can do is check if a instance of the type described by the `Type` object could be assigned to a variable of type `Type`. This gives the desired result, because `RuntimeType` derives from `Type`:

```
private bool IsTypeOfType(Type type)
{
    return typeof(Type).IsAssignableFrom(type);
}
```

---

If you really need to know the `Type` object that describes the `Type` class, you can use the GetType Method:

```
private bool IsRuntimeType(Type type)
{
    return type == typeof(Type).GetType();
}
```

However, because `typeof(Type) != typeof(Type).GetType()`, you should avoid this.

---

*Examples:*

```
IsTypeOfType(typeof(Type))                          // true
IsTypeOfType(typeof(Type).GetType())                // true
IsTypeOfType(typeof(string))                        // false
IsTypeOfType(typeof(int))                           // false

IsRuntimeType(typeof(Type))                         // false
IsRuntimeType(typeof(Type).GetType())               // true
IsRuntimeType(typeof(string))                       // false
IsRuntimeType(typeof(int))                          // false
```

Comment: I don't understand, won't your `IsTypeOfType()` always return `true`?

Comment: @svick: I've added a few examples.

Comment: The examples here are not very relevant. What about the runtime Type obtained like this `new {}.GetType()`? I've tried it and the result is `false` (while it should be true) meaning it's wrong. In .NET 4.5, we have `TypeInfo` and looks like the check `type is TypeInfo` seems to be OK to check if t's runtime type or not.

Comment: @Hopeless I actually upvoted your comment thinking you were right -- however I then did a test (see my answer below) and found the opposite. I'd really appreciate to know whether I'm right or wrong there.

Answer (score 0):

Really, the only trouble is that `System.RuntimeType` is `internal`, so doing something simple like:

```cs
   if (obj is System.RuntimeType)
```

does not compile:

> CS0122 'RuntimeType' is inaccessible due to its protection level.

So the solution from @dtb above is right. Expanding on their answer:

```cs
void Main()
{
    object obj = "";
    // obj = new {}; // also works

    // This works
    IsRuntimeType(obj.GetType()); // Rightly prints "it's a System.Type"
    IsRuntimeType(obj.GetType().GetType()); // Rightly prints "it's a System.RuntimeType"

    // This proves that @Hopeless' comment to the accepted answer from @dtb does not work
    IsWhatSystemType(obj.GetType()); // Should return "is a Type", but doesn't
    IsWhatSystemType(obj.GetType().GetType());
}

// This works
void IsRuntimeType(object obj)
{
    if (obj == typeof(Type).GetType())
        // Can't do `obj is System.RuntimeType` -- inaccessible due to its protection level
        Console.WriteLine("object is a System.RuntimeType");
    else if (obj is Type)
        Console.WriteLine("object is a System.Type");
}

// This proves that @Hopeless' comment to the accepted answer from @dtb does not work
void IsWhatSystemType(object obj)
{
    if (obj is TypeInfo)
        Console.WriteLine("object is a System.RuntimeType");
    else
        Console.WriteLine("object is a Type");
}
```

Working .NET fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/0WIUdQ).

Comment: Right the first line it prints you can see that it's wrong, it prints `object is a System.Type` in case you pass in `new {}.GetType()`, `new {}` should be of a runtime Type, so to use the `IsRuntimeType` method (by `dtb`), we need to get its `Type` by using `GetType` (or any other possible way?) before checking if `new {}` is of a runtime type or not. Why do you pass `new {}.GetType().GetType()` in that `IsRuntimeType`? That checks against the `Type` itself (Type of Type) rather than the object type (of `new {}`)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. However, I'm not sure I follow. If we do `new { }.GetType().ToString()` we get `<>f__AnonymousType0`. Why do you say *`new {}` should be of a runtime Type*? I don't think that's the case -- isn't it an AnonymousType? Hence the code.

Comment: In `IsRuntimeType()`, if you pass in `new {}.GetType()` it prints *object is a System.Type* (it's an AnonymousType); if you pass in `new {}.GetType().GetType()` it prints *object is a System.RuntimeType*.

Comment: Maybe I have a misunderstanding about `System.RuntimeType` which is actually just a derived type from `Type` to represent type of type (I'm not so sure about how instances of `System.RuntimeType` are created but maybe one way is call `GetType()` on a `Type`). I thought it's a general term about all dynamically created types (which once more time confused me with anonymous types although anonymous types are still compile-time created types - they are just hidden and auto-gen by compiler). So to test the `IsRuntimeType`, we need to create some type at runtime (maybe using emit reflection)

Comment: I admit that `anonymous type` is not a runtime type which we can use to test the method `IsRuntimeType`, we need some real instance of `System.RuntimeType`, creating a type at runtime using emit reflection is not very easy, so I do not intend to dig in making a demo for this check now. I'm not so sure if that kind of dynamically created type can have `GetType` called on it returning `System.RuntimeType`

Answer (score -1):

```
return type == typeof(MyObjectType) || isoftype(type.BaseType) ;
```

Comment: Code without an explanation is not very useful, especially if you use a method that you don't explain.